# Orientation of ellipse model in skimage.measure

Tags: image-processing, orientation, ellipse, scikit-image

I used ellipse model from skimage.measure to fit the blob of bright points shown in the left side images. I want to calculate the orientation of the fit ellipse.  The reference axis with which the orientation of the fit ellipse is measured by skimage.measure is ambiguous. In some cases, the orientation is measured with respect to vertical axis (as shown in Fig. 1) and sometimes with horizontal axis (as shown in Fig. 2). The orientation angles are given in small white box in the right image. Please help me undestand why this is occurring and how to calculate orientation angles with respect to horizontal axis only.

Thanks in advance!

Image 1 vertical orientation:

[image: img]

Image 2 horizontal orientation:

[image: img]

Comment: Relevant issue: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2646

Comment: @Stefan van der Walt Thank you for the link! I have already checked it before but I am unable to get the answers.

Comment: Please share your code.